# Problemas com Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, querybuilder

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao tentar implementar uma consulta 
com joins, no query builder:

Minha Consulta (SQL puro):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
orgao.sigla AS sigla_org_uni 
FROM protocolo 
INNER JOIN procedimento p ON protocolo.id_protocolo = p.id_procedimento 
INNER JOIN unidade uni_ger 
INNER JOIN orgao ON uni_ger.id_orgao = orgao.id_orgao 
ON protocolo.id_unidade_geradora = uni_ger.id_unidade 
WHERE protocolo.sta_protocolo='P' 
AND protocolo.sta_nivel_acesso_global<>'2' 
GROUP BY uni_ger.id_orgao, orgao.sigla 
ORDER BY orgao.sigla ASC
```

Minha consulta com o Query Builder:

```
DB::select(`orgao.sigla as sigla_org_uni`)
         ->addSelect(DB::raw(`COUNT(*) as total`))
    ->from(`protocolo`)
    ->join(`procedimento as p`, function($join) {
        $join->on(`protocolo.id_protocolo`, `=`, `p.id_procedimento`);
        })
    ->from(`unidade as uni_ger`)
    ->join(`orgao`, function($join) {
        $join->on(`protocolo.id_unidade_geradora`, `=`, `uni_ger.id_unidade`);
        })
    ->where(`protocolo.sta_protocolo`, `=`, `P`)
    ->where(`protocolo.sta_nivel_acesso_global`, `<>`, 2)
    ->groupBy(`uni_ger.id_orgao`)
    ->groupBy(`orgao.sigla`)
    ->orderBy(`orgao.sigla`, `ASC`)
    ->get();
```

Tenho quase certeza que a consulta dentro do query builder está correta,
porém quando a chamo dentro da aplicação, o Laravel retorna o seguinte
erro:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Invalid object name 'procedimento'. 
[20018] (severity 16) [(null)] (SQL: select [orgao].[sigla] as 
[sigla_org_uni], COUNT(*) as total from [unidade] as [uni_ger] inner join 
[procedimento] as [p] on [protocolo].[id_protocolo] = [p].[id_procedimento] 
inner join [orgao] on [protocolo].[id_unidade_geradora] = [uni_ger].
[id_unidade] where [protocolo].[sta_protocolo] = P and [protocolo].
[sta_nivel_acesso_global] <> 2 group by [uni_ger].[id_orgao], [orgao].
[sigla] order by [orgao].[sigla] asc)
```

Comment: olha só sua SQL ta assim `INNER JOIN unidade uni_ger` e no Builder está assim `->from(`unidade as uni_ger`)`, parece que tem algo errado ai! dá uma olhada! e parece que na SQL já tem problemas

Comment: aqui tem outro problema `->where(`protocolo.sta_protocolo`, `=`, `P`)` porque se for uma string daquela letra então é aspas simples (ou dupla) exemplo `->where(`protocolo.sta_protocolo`, `=`, 'P')`, ou seja, o seu codigo tem problemas na SQL e na Builder

Comment: Pois é! esse caso é bastante peculiar, tendo-se em vista que eu ainda não encontrei nenhum exemplo para implementar um join no query builder em que não tenha 'ON'. Por exemplo, gostaria de saber como posso fazer para converter de sql puro (INNER JOIN unidade uni_ger) para Query Builder. Acredito que esta seja a fonte do problema aqui. Desde já, agradeço pelo feedback @VirgilioNovic !

Comment: Se você colocar a `SQL` certinha eu faço uma resposta com ela, é que em um dos inner join está faltando ! dá uma olhada lá

Answer (score 0):

Pelos comentários um [join](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_join) feito no `Builder` é basicamente:

```
$this join(string $table, 
           string $one, 
           string $operator = null, 
           string $two = null, 
           string $type = 'inner', 
           bool $where = false)
```

Então nessa `SQL` é isso que pode ser gerado basicamente:

```
DB::selectRaw('orgao.sigla, count(*) as total')
    ->from('protocolo')
    ->join(`procedimento`,'protocolo.id_protocolo','=','procedimento.id_procedimento') 
    ->join('unidade','protocolo.id_unidade_geradora','=','unidade.id_unidade')  
    ->where('protocolo.sta_protocolo','=', 'P')
    ->where('protocolo.sta_nivel_acesso_global', '<>', 2)    
    ->groupBy('orgao.sigla')
    ->orderBy('orgao.sigla')
    ->get();
```

mas, faltou passar na sua pergunta a tabela `orgao` o seu relacionamento e talvez mais alguns detalhes pra que a resposta seja um exemplo válido para a sua pergunta...

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

1) Fiz algumas alterações no JOIN da minha query e mesma ficou assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
orgao.sigla AS sigla_org_uni 
FROM protocolo 
JOIN procedimento p ON protocolo.id_protocolo = p.id_procedimento 
JOIN unidade uni_ger ON protocolo.id_unidade_geradora = uni_ger.id_unidade 
JOIN orgao ON uni_ger.id_orgao = orgao.id_orgao 
WHERE protocolo.sta_protocolo='P' 
AND protocolo.sta_nivel_acesso_global<>'2' 
AND orgao.sigla <> 'xx'
AND orgao.sigla <> 'xx'
GROUP BY uni_ger.id_orgao, orgao.sigla 
ORDER BY orgao.sigla ASC
```

2) A implementação final no query builder ficou assim:

```
$data = Protocolo::select('orgao.sigla as sigla_org_uni')
            ->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'))
            ->from('protocolo')
            ->join('procedimento as p', function($join) {
                $join->on('protocolo.id_protocolo', '=', 'p.id_procedimento');
                })
            ->join('unidade as uni_ger', function($join) {
                $join->on('protocolo.id_unidade_geradora', '=', 'uni_ger.id_unidade');
                })
            ->join('orgao', function($join) {
                $join->on('uni_ger.id_orgao', '=', 'orgao.id_orgao');
                })
            ->where('protocolo.sta_protocolo', '=', 'P')
            ->where('protocolo.sta_nivel_acesso_global', '<>', 2)
            ->where('orgao.sigla', '<>', 'xx')
            ->where('orgao.sigla', '<>', 'xx')
            ->groupBy('uni_ger.id_orgao')
            ->groupBy('orgao.sigla')
            ->orderBy('orgao.sigla', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

Desde já, agradeço pela atenção @Virgilio Novic. Esta é a primeira vez em que estou postando no Stack Overflow e perdoe-me caso eu tenha dito alguma besteira. =P